# Acquiring audio samples Windows 8/RT

Tags: windows, audio, windows-runtime

I need to build an app that acquires audio from microphone and elaborates it "realtime"(as soon as they are ready).

I ask to you how to get audio samples from microphone on Windows 8/ Win RT, without saving them on a file, but using them directly from an array (a buffer) in order to do my elaboration.

Thanks to everybody :-)

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to use local storage if you don't want to save the captured data into a file. See one example on using application data at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ApplicationData-sample-fb043eb2

Comment: Thanks Zhiming for your answer, but my problem is how to get the samples I need. I'd like to work only using ram, but first i need to get samples.